# Unable to start MySQL CLOUD9

Tags: mysql, cloud9-ide

I can not start MySQL on cloud 9.

If I execute:

```
sudo mysql-ctl status
```

I get: MySQL is stopped

But if I execute:

```
sudo mysql-ctl start
```

It doesn't make nothing, and MySQL keep stopped.

I don't know what to do because I can not reboot. Some ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Did it work in the past, is this local or internet server?

Comment: It worked the other day. It's a free account with a free workspace in c9.io, thanks for your interest.

Comment: It is possibly a problem on the server end; try contacting your host.

Comment: Can you contact support@c9.io with your username and the workspace having this problem? I'd be happy to help.

Answer (score -1):

```
mysql-ctl install
```

then

```
mysql-ctl cli
```